# In the Euclidean Ring ${\Bbb Z}_3[x]$, what is the remainder of the euclidean division of $x^4+2x^3+x^2+2x+2$ by $x^2+2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

So far I've $(x^2+2)(x^2+2x-1)+4-2x$   but the options for the remainder are:
$2x+1$,
$2x$,
$x+1$, or
$x$.

Comment: What do you denote  $\mathbb Z_3$? Integers modulo $3$ or $3$-adic integers?

Comment: A better notation is $\Bbb Z/(3)$, or $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$. Clearly $4-2x=1+x$.

Comment: And even $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$…

Comment: Imo the nicest, clearest notation is $\;\Bbb F_3[x]\;$ .

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$-2=1\pmod 3\;,\;\;4=1\pmod 3\;$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Remember that the coefficients aren't from $\Bbb Z$, they are in $\Bbb Z_3$.